# Android Studio need to rebuild project before each run

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently the android studio shows Error Java cannot find Symbol or each run. i have to go to built and rebuilt the project before each run. Is there any way to fix it? 
i don't know if my project problem or the problem of the latest update of android studio. 
is anyone facing the same problem ? any way to fix it?

Comment: I have this problme recently on a Android studio 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56843). Maybe you should try this:

> Same issue here, to avoid rebuild EACH TIME, i'm going to my module project settings -> Dependencies and up or down one of my library item ->  Apply -> Ok -> Make regenerating R.java.

You could also try unchecking "Use external build" in compiler settings:

> File -> Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) -> Compiler -> Uncheck "Use external build"

Comment: your solution doesn't work with Android Studio 3.2.1 (external build)

Comment: I can't find it in Android studio 3.5.3

Answer (score 19):

Please check run/debug configuration.Make sure include ‘Gradle-aware Make’
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked great for me :)

Comment: Thanks this solution is perfect. Made my day

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works on AS 3.4

Comment: How can I add it??

Comment: What does it do??

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Why was it missing tho.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

in android studio version 2+, use this in all gradle config files

```
android{
..

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        incremental = false;
}
...

}
```

and if you have experimental for ndk use like this

```
model {
    android.compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        incremental false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about the problem in your 2013, but in mine 2016 (Android Studio 2.1.3) instant run forces Android Studio to rebuild the project from the scratch every time I press "Debug". Switching it off solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had changed the *sourceSets*:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res',
                            'src/main/res/layouts',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/content',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/layout',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/fragment',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/dialog',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/appbar',
                    ]
        }
    }
}
```

and locate some `*.xml` to `layouts/layout` directory...

finally I got the problem, don't place file in `layouts/layout` directory, so I created an `activity` directory and cut that files to `activity` directory, and finally edit the gradle this way:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res',
                            'src/main/res/layouts',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/activity',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/content',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/layout',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/fragment',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/dialog',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/appbar',
                    ]
        }
    }
}
```