# Android Studio Requires rebuild every run

Tags: android, compilation, launch, rebuild

**Android Studio** is giving me an absolute nightmare! 
Every build I attempt probably has a 15% chance of actually compiling correctly and installing on my device. I have to use `Log.d` to see if the changes actually are running! (FYI: It definitely drives someone insane!)

The only way to get reliable builds is to hit "`rebuild project`" before every run - but it takes huge amounts of time and human patience :O - to do this every build.

I have read similar threads on stack overflow, but they all deal with older versions of Android Studio and don't really apply to my version. I have *upgraded from 1.1 to 1.2* and finally to a *beta 1.3 release* - the same symptoms still apply.

Offline mode does not help, nor does messing with Gradle files..
Could it have something to do with `R.java` issues? I am not sure.

Any thoughts?

Regards,
Droideh

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: Have a look here, this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47966808/2987847

Answer (score 0):

Boosting your Gradle Script with the help of following:

Upgrade to Gradle 2.4

add the following at the end of your root build.grade script.

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}
```

change gradle properties

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

For complete update on gradle please go through [official post](https://medium.com/@erikhellman/boosting-the-performance-for-gradle-in-your-android-projects-6d5f9e4580b6)

Comment: Thanks, but the issue has not been resolved. I have changed a critcal **Log.d()** function and the output still has not been changed to reflect this. Any other thoughts?