# AndroidStudio: Run app sometime not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Windows with current `AndroidStudio` version is 2.1.1.
Sometime I run my app by `Run app` button (Shift+F10) my app won't start.
When it's happened, I always use `Build -> Rebuild Project` then `Run app` and my app will start normally
However, now my project bigger and my computer performance is not good so `Rebuild Project` take too much time (about 1-2 minutes)

Can I run my app again without `Rebuild Project`? And why my app sometime won't start?
Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: You really need to rebuild so that it will regenerate a new test apk.

Comment: You may try regenerating your R.java and try unchecking "Use external build" in compiler settings as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269421/android-studio-need-to-rebuild-project-before-each-run

Answer (score 0):

How about use this button: Rerun. This will build your project again without clean task, it should be fast.

[image: Android studio toolbar]