# Android Studio needs clean after each run/build

Tags: android, android-studio

My project is made of two modules (app and a library) and since a while(I seem to remeber it happening before the instant run was added) I need to clean the project before each build/run. This is really boring and time consuming beside making the whole instant run thing basically impossible to use.

When building without cleaning what gradle says is that it couldn't find a class(that clearly exists as if it didn't the run wouldn't work after a clean)

Does anyone have a solution for this issue? Might the multidex be involved in this?

I've already read this [Android Studio need to rebuild project before each run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269421/android-studio-need-to-rebuild-project-before-each-run) but, beside being old, it didn't word for me.

UPDATE Logs

[image: Console]

[image: Gradle Console]

Comment: post the log where you find the issue

Comment: @Charuka added the gradle log

Comment: grrrrr when you add it copy and paste it next time,its easy for others to read -_-

Comment: I tried doing so but SO didn't keep the formatting of the text, tried to add it as code as well but couldn't parse it well

Comment: you have a conflict issue with a dependency try this -->  exclude it and check if works if not update me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460148/dependency-ignored-because-of-conflict-android-studio

Comment: @Charuka I excluded the dependency that caused the conflict and indeed the warning is not shown anymore but the problem isn't solved. I get same logs from both gradle and messages

Comment: post the log error so i can read it

Comment: both gradle console and message are exactly the same as before, the only difference is that there is no more the warning line with the yellow triangle.

Comment: Hi @AlbertoBrambilla have you find any solution? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

Instant run in android studio is having problem . I had this problem for a long days back. Disabling the instant run is the only way to clean and run project to avoid class problem. Instant run uses class update process .So If we run apk in some phones, problem occurs So i disabled the instant run. I think instant run development in beta process.

Comment: I tried that but the problem isn't solved, I guess it is not related to instant run